# Inequality proof-check

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Prove that if $|x-x_0|<\min\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\left(|y_0|+1\right)},1\right)\quad$  and $\quad|y-y_0|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2\left(|x_0|+1\right)}$, then $|xy -x_0y_0|<\varepsilon$.

\begin{align}
|y-y_0| &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}\\
|y-y_0|(|x_0|+1)&< \varepsilon/2\\
|y-y_0|(|x_0|+|x-x_0|)&< \varepsilon/2\\
|y-y_0||x_0+(x-x_0)|&<\varepsilon/2\\
|y-y_0||x|&<\varepsilon/2\\
|xy-xy_0|&<\varepsilon/2\\
|xy-xy_0|-|x-x_0|&<\varepsilon/2
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
|x-x_0|&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}\\
(|y_0)|+1)|x-x_0|&<\varepsilon/2\\
|y_0||x-x_0|+|x-x_0|&<\varepsilon/2\\
|y_0x-y_0x_0|+|x-x_0|&<\varepsilon/2\\
\end{align}

Adding the first and second results:
\begin{align}
|xy-xy_0|-|x-x_0|+|y_0x-y_0x_0|+|x-x_0|&<\varepsilon\\
|xy-xy_0|+|y_0x-y_0x_0|<\varepsilon\\
|(xy-xy_0)+(y_0x-x_0y_0)|<\varepsilon
\\|xy-x_0y_0|<\varepsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$|x-x_0|<\min \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)},1\right)$$
just means that $|x-x_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}$ and $|x-x_0|<1$ at the same time. 
Now, since
$$|x|-|x_0|\le |x-x_0|<1$$
we can say that $|x|<1+|x_0|$. Finally, note that
$$\begin{align}
|xy-x_0y_0|&=|x(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)| \\
&\leq |x||y-y_0|+|y_0||x-x_0| \\
&<(1+|x_0|)\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}+|y_0|\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)} \\
&= \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{|y_0|+1}\right)\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align}$$